# Using Visual Studio to create an XML file, Cant figure out how to make the output in .xml format?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xmlwriter

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a project that creates a .xml file.  However I am having trouble with creating a file that is in .xml format, it is currently just outputs as a file format without the .xml.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub saveXML_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveXML.Click

        Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        ' Initialize the XmlWriter.
        Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(txtConsumerID.Text.ToString(), settings)

        With XmlWrt

            ' Write the Xml declaration.
            .WriteStartDocument()


            ' Write the root element.
            .WriteStartElement("PIAlertMonitor")


            .WriteStartElement("ConsumerID")
            .WriteString(txtConsumerID.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()

            .WriteStartElement("MaxAlerts")
            .WriteString(MaxAlerts.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()

            .WriteStartElement("Notification")

            .WriteStartElement("MailTo")

            .WriteStartElement("eMail")
            .WriteString(txteMail.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()


            ' The end of this person.
            .WriteEndElement()

            ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
            .WriteEndDocument()
            .Close()

        End With

        MessageBox.Show("XML File Saved")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called an **extension**.

If you want to create a file with an extension, you need to create a filename that includes an extension, using string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You filename is stored in `txtConsumerID.Text`, if you want it to end in .xml, you will need to make sure your user ends it's input with .xml or you need to take the variable and append the string ".xml" yourself.

[System.IO.Path and it's methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: how would I go about taking the variable and appending the the string .xml to it every time?  I am trying to look at the link you provided me with, thanks